# Is int in C# and Python the same thing?

Tags: c#, python, sockets, tcp

I need to send a integer from C# to Python over the network and It hit me that if the "rules" are the same in both languages, and the bytesize of them are the same that should be the buffer size and i could just `int(val)` in Python... cant I?

Both have the size 32-bit, so in Python and C# I should be able to set

C#:

```cs
String str = ((int)(RobotCommands.standstill | RobotCommands.turncenter)).ToString();
Stream stream = client.GetStream();

ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] ba = asen.GetBytes(str);

stream.Write(ba, 0, 32);
```

Python:

```python
while True:
    data = int( conn.recv(32) );

    print "received data:", data    

    if( (data & 0x8) == 0x8 ):
        print("STANDSTILL");

    if( (data & 0x20) == 0x20 ):
        print("MOVEBACKWARDS");
```

Comment: Why not just try it and see what happens?

Comment: @MichaelMauderer There may be some obscure case in which it'd go wrong. I see no problem in asking this.

Comment: Does your C# code even run? You're claiming the string representation of your int has 32 bytes, which it clearly hasn't.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the semantics of python's `recv`, but in many user languages this won't work, because it might return partial data when reading from TCP.

Comment: @Jason94: in this case, trying it is a good thing to do first.  You'll discover right away that it doesn't work.

Comment: I would ask: Why are you sending it as string encoded ? Just send the 4 bytes of the underlying value. No need for strings here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = int( conn.recv(32) );
```

1. That is 32 bytes not 32 bits
2. That is a maximum, you may get less then you request
3. `int(string)` does stuff like `int('42') == 42`, and `int('-56') == -56`. That is it converts a human readable number into an int. But that's not what you are dealing with here.

You want to do something like this

```
# see python's struct documentation, this defines the format of data you want
data = struct.Struct('>i') 
# this produces an object from the socket that acts more like a file
socket_file = conn.makefile()
# read the data and unpack it
# NOTE: this will fail if the connection is lost midway through the bytes
# dealing with that is left as an exercise to the reader
value, = data.unpack(socket_file.read(data.size))
```

**EDIT**

It looks like you are also sending the data incorrectly in the C# code. I don't know C#, so I can't tell you how to do it correctly. Anybody who does, feel free to edit in the corrections.